# React Native | Controlling Parameters Passed to a ListView's renderRow Function

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

According to the [React Native Docs for `ListView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) the signature for the renderRow function has the following signature:

```
(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => renderable
```

However, in the [`ScheduleView` component](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/tabs/schedule/ScheduleListView.js) in the F8App app by Facebook, `PureListView` which renders a `ListView` uses a renderRow function with this signature:

```
renderRow(session: Session, day: number)
```

How is this? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because f8 app uses flow. See https://flowtype.org/

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't realize that it was the same row data and section ID that were being passed and your answer gave me the nudge I needed to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I didn't realize was that it's the same row data and section ID that are being passed. I thought that it was completely customized data being passed instead but upon examination of the actual data it's now clear that the data is simply grouped by time (even though the param name is `day`) which really is just the section ID.

Then, as agent_hunt pointed out, they are typed using flow.

[image: ListView data grouped by day/time (section) each with multiple rows.]